# SQL Reverse sum operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, reverse

I have the following table:

```
unixtime    byte_sent   byte_received   session_id
---------------------------------------------------
1543569405  8           12              1
1543569404  8           12              1
1543569403  8           12              1
1543569402  8           12              1
1543569401  8           12              1
1543569410  15          25              2
1543569409  15          25              2
1543569408  15          25              2
1543569407  15          25              2
1543569411  10          30              3
1543569410  10          30              3
1543569409  10          30              3
1543569408  10          30              3
1543569407  10          30              3
1543569406  10          30              3
1543569405  10          30              3
```

Then I have the following SQL query:

```
select
    session_id,
    max(unixtime) as session_end_time,
    sum(byte_sent) as byte_sent_tot,
    sum(byte_received) as byte_received_tot,
    count(*) as duration
from
    table
group by
    session_id
order by 
    session_end_time
```

The result is the following:

```
session_id  session_end_time    byte_sent_tot   byte_received_tot   duration
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           1543569405          40              60                  5
2           1543569410          60              100                 4
3           1543569411          70              210                 7
```

I need the reverse query to go back from the result to the original table.

The assumption is that session_end_time should be spanned one by one for each seconds of the duration and the total byte can be divided by duration, in this way I will obtain an average value of byte/s.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a jolly challenge, but I don't quite understand the actual question! Could you add sample output to clarify your last paragraph?

Comment: You are right, but the real question is about the procedure (if possible), not really related to the DB. In my case I have postresql

Comment: The situation is this: I have a firewall that generate a traffic log (a table entry) with the information of session_id, session_end_time, sent_bytes_tot, received_bytes_tot, duration. But This information is not usefull to understand the bandwitdh of the session, I need to explode the average value to have the bandwitdh per second, and then I will sum every average in that second for each session to have the real medium bandwith in that second and obtain a graph of the bandwidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is an even distribution of records for each session_id for the columns
we can do the following

```
with data
  as (select session_id, /*This is the Input query which the user has obtained.*/
             max(unixtime) as session_end_time,
             sum(byte_sent) as byte_sent_tot,
             sum(byte_received) as byte_received_tot,
             count(*) as duration
        from t
     group by session_id
     order by session_end_time
     )
select a.session_id
      ,a.session_end_time - b.col  + 1 as unixtime
      ,b.col  
      ,a.byte_sent_tot/a.duration as byte_sent /*Distribute evenly based on the count*/
      ,a.byte_received_tot/a.duration as byte_received
  from data a
   cross join generate_series(1,a.duration) as b(col)
```

Comment: Fantastic! The only limit is that I don't know the series lenght, that can be a very high number, but it is my duration field, but the generate_series doesn't know the table a

Comment: The value expected in the generate_series(1,n) is the max_value of duration column. In your example its 7. I used 100 as an example.

Comment: Any value less than the max_value of duration column is fine

Comment: @Alessio: you don't need to hardcode the upper limit you pass to `generate_series()` you can use the duration column directly. I have edited George's answer to reflect that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks for the input, i wasnt aware of that